# Bash difference between pipeline and parameters

Tags: bash, stdin, readline, pipeline

I need to write a script which gets a file from stdin and run over the lines of it.

My question is can I do something like that :

```
TheFile= /dev/stdin
while read line; do
{
 ....
}
done<"$(TheFile)"
```

or can I write `--done<"$1"`

or in that case the minute I send a parameter to the function which is a file it will be sent to the while function ?

Answer (score 1):

Where to start... Are you sure're up for this?

What are you trying to do with the lines of the file? You might be better off not iterating like your example, just using `sed`, `awk`, or `grep` on it like this example:

```
sed -e 's/apple/banana/' $TheFile
```

That will output the contents of $TheFile, replacing all occurrences of "apple" with "banana". That's a trivial example, but you could do much more.

If you really want to loop, then remove the `$()` from your example. Also, you cannot have a space after `=` in your code.

Comment: I'm not allowed to user sed or awk :\
And what I want to do is each line has a date d.m..y
that can be either:
05.1.2016
5.01.2016
5.1.2016

and what I need to do is print all of them like 5.1.2016

Comment: Sounds like this is a homework assignment then. Good luck with your learning.